# smallestCountry function inputting and output incorrectly

Tags: c++

This code is looking into a delimited file and finding the country with the smallest overall area, I made two sets of definitions for the strings in order to compare them. The code is outputting the information for the largestCountry function instead of the smallest country.

```
while (!in.fail())
{
    if (minArea == 0 || Area < minArea)
    {
        readRecord(in, ISO2, ISO32, ISONumeric2, fips2, Country2, Capital2,
            Area2, Population2, Continent2, tld2, CurrencyCode2, CurrencyName2, Phone2,
            PostalCodeForm2, PostalCodeRegex2, Languages2, geonameid2, neighbors2,
            EquivalentFipsCode2);

        minArea = Area2;
    }
    else {
        readRecord(in, ISO, ISO3, ISONumeric, fips, Country, Capital,
            Area, Population, Continent, tld, CurrencyCode, CurrencyName, Phone,
            PostalCodeForm, PostalCodeRegex, Languages, geonameid, neighbors,
            EquivalentFipsCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't work with a `<` , put a `>`...

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing because we lack a *lot* of information:

```
// some init of Area & minArea here

while (!in.fail()) {
    if (Area < minArea) {
        minArea = Area;
    }
    readRecord(in, ISO, ISO3, ISONumeric, fips, Country, Capital,
        Area, Population, Continent, tld, CurrencyCode, CurrencyName, Phone,
        PostalCodeForm, PostalCodeRegex, Languages, geonameid, neighbors,
        EquivalentFipsCode);

}
```

Comment: Or unconditionally, `minArea = std::min(minArea, Area);`